# Mongodb - Use a regex search to match embedded documents

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo Collection :

```
db.sCriteria.insert({criteria : {a:"1",b:"2",c:"3"}})
db.sCriteria.insert({criteria : {a:"1",d:"2",e:"3"}})
```

The properties of the embedded document "criteria" can vary a lot so I chose to index the whole object :

```
db.sCriteria.ensureIndex({criteria : 1})
```

And my queries are always against the entire object to use the index. Ex :

```
db.sCriteria.find({criteria : {a:"1",b:"2",c:"3"}}).count() 
1
db.sCriteria.find({criteria : {a:"1",b:"2"}}).count() 
0
```

What I want to be able to do is to use regex for some property.
For example :

```
db.sCriteria.find({criteria : {a:"1",b:"2",c:/3/}}).count()
```

This always gives 0 results

Is there a way to do this and use the index?

Answer (score 2):

Your query may not return any document if what you are querying is subdocument because the field [order matter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents).The best thing to do is to create a [coumpound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) and use the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
db.sCriteria.count({ "criteria.a": "1", "criteria.b": "2", "criteria.c": /3/})
```

Comment: In this case my index will not be used. And I can't create an index for each property because in reality I have other properties with which I index the criteria object, which will make it very complex

Comment: you don't need to  index every fields  in your subdocument absolutely not. you can use compound indexes

Comment: The index I described is only used to find the whole object. It's not used with your proposition